# Eclipse RCP [Linux]: Missing requirements when running RCP while they are in "Plugin dependencies"

Tags: eclipse, plugins, rcp

I get many missing packages when running my RCP from inside eclipse.

but, when I go to "configure build path", I found that these dependencies are there !!

some missing requirements like

```
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets.source_3.4.100.
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.console.source_3.5.100.
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.editors.source_3.7.0.
```

while they are found in the build path of the plugin ... Am I missing something ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The plugins are listed in your MANIFEST.MF?

You got a launch-config where the plugins are correctly listed?

In the launch-config, on Tab "Plugins", set "launch with all workspace and enabled target plugins".

That should work.